# Can reading a word trigger a trauma flashback?

Tags: psychology, sexual-abuse

It is a well known fact that some situations may trigger flashbacks of trauma in PTSD sufferers, like going to some places, or seeing particular scenes in movies or TV.

Lately I've seen many mentions of trigger "words". The idea is that, for example, *reading* the word "rape" would induce a flashback in a rape victim.

[Example of such a claim](http://www.ptsdconnect.com/discussions/1749-faced-with-a-trigger-word-in-class) in which the word is "bitch". (Note this has 404ed since the question was asked).

I am skeptical of the idea since the [Wikipedia page for trauma trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_trigger) does not mention it, and even contains more than one instance of the word "rape". This [feminism wikia](http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/Trigger_warning) also agrees that the correct usage of "trigger warning" has to do with the content and not simply the usage of a word.

In fact, it's not [uncommon to find people with PTSD](https://www.myptsd.com/c/threads/trigger-warnings-and-trigger-words.41298/) complaining that this kind of "trigger words" trivialize the real mental illness and its victims.

Comment: The referenced feminism wikia page also says, "The phrase "trigger warning" may itself be triggering to some trauma survivors."

Comment: @ChrisW: That's what I have always wondered about. Does [Ironic Process Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironic_process_theory) make trigger warnings self-fulfilling?

Comment: I didn't find the example of a schoolkid calling "bitch" her trigger word very satisfying; it appeared to be a word she is sensitive to and angered by, but not related to PTSD or flashbacks.

Comment: I think the issue is when one see it out of the blue, in a place he/she did not expect to see it. When reading article about rape it's OK but when browsing programming site and suddenly seeing the "R" word... this can be a problem in my opinion. It's like suddenly bumping into the rapist on the street vs. seeing him in TV or in a picture where you're prepared to see him.

Comment: Note that the effect of triggers is defined more broadly on the wikipedia page you link. You talk about flashbacks, which refers to recalling a past event with such strength that it's as if you're re-experiencing it. Trauma triggers simply cause the victim to recall their trauma. Since this may lead to a spiral of negative thought or take a lot of energy to deal with, a trigger warning can be helpful. But there are no explicit claims that words can cause genuine flashbacks in anything you've linked.

Comment: I'm not saying that rape or sexual abuse isn't serious matters, but comparing what Vietnam veterans suffer to it seems a bit _excessive_.

Comment: @Peter if you can provide factual evidence for your statements, then it could be a good answer. Please don't use the comments to pseduo-answer without actual evidence though (sorry, people abuse this massively on the site).

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm not answering, I'm trying to clarify the question. It is based on the premise that single words are claimed to cause flashbacks, and I don't think that claim has been made anywhere. Your evidence is reading mentions of trigger words, but I think those mentions do not refer to triggering _flashbacks_. You may have misread the phrase "trigger word" in which case you should rephrase/delete the question or I may be wrong in my interpretation, in which case you can add a quote, so we have a more specific claim to evaluate.

Comment: @Peter the last link I provided agrees with me though.

Comment: @Sklivvz Fair enough, but they're discussing the same question you are, and from the same assumption: that trigger warnings are there to stop people experiencing flashbacks. I'm not sure this is true. Whether it's true or not doesn't strictly affect the answer to your question, but it might affect whether or not that's what you really wanted to ask.

Comment: @Peter it doesn't really matter if it's true, it matters if people *believe it to be true*, that's what a notable claim is. If enough people think there's this relationship, then it's worthwhile showing the evidence around it.

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, but then there are two claims: 1) "trigger warnings are used to prevent flashbacks" and 2) "a single word can cause a flashback" We have clear evidence that people believe the first claim (and it would make an interesting question). Your question is about the second claim.

Comment: @Peter here's an example of someone using a trigger warning for a single word usage: https://newrepublic.com/article/121820/my-students-need-trigger-warnings-and-professors-do-too

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm sorry, but I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say. I'm happy to accept that trigger warnings are used for single words. I'm skeptical that trigger warnings are used _to prevent flashbacks_. I don't think anybody who uses trigger warnings believes that is their purpose, and yet that is what your question implies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51783/discussion-between-sklivvz-and-peter).

Comment: This strikes me as not objectively answerable. Psychology is not an exact science, and there's no way to "disprove" that someone's PTSD was triggered by any particular thing. If you want to be strict, if at least 1 person with PTSD ever claimed to be triggered by a word then yes, words can do that in and of themselves.

Comment: @Magisch psychology has objective answers all the time on this site. There's plenty of ways to prove and disprove assertions scientifically.

Comment: @Sklivvz How would you prove if someone is traumatized from reading a word somewhere when "traumatized" or "flashbacks" in and of themselves aren't objective measures. Sure there are signs like increased heart rate and sweating but if I told you right now your comment traumatized me you'd have no way to disprove that, ever. In essence, by our imprecise understanding, someone is traumatized or triggered when they say they are, and that's the end of it.

Comment: @Magisch the question is not about single cases. The question is about a phenomenon, proving or disproving which requires larger scale studies than anecdotes. In any case: a person claiming this on the internet is worthess; a documented medical case is better; a small scale study better still; a large scale test even more so; a systematic study is perfect. This is valid not only for this question, but in general on the site.

Comment: @Sklivvz "Does this happen" requires only 1 case to be proof positive, IIRC.

Comment: You are skeptical because Wikipedia failed to mention something?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, according to the definition of 'trigger' given by Oxford Dictionaries:

> **[trigger](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trigger)**
>
> verb [with object]
>
> 1.3 (especially of something **read**, seen, or heard) distress (someone), typically as a result of arousing feelings or memories associated with a particular traumatic experience:

(emphasis mine)

Oxford Dictionaries Online, 'trigger'

Trauma-survivors report that a single word can be sufficient to act as a 'trigger':

> It took years for Lindsey to find her way to a therapist, where she discovered that the occasional flashbacks, phantom sensations of being touched, and breathlessness she experienced in the wake of this violation were symptoms of post-traumatic stress disorder. The episodes struck whenever she **saw** or **read** **words** associated with sexual violence: rape, molest, attack, even incest. She’d notice a tingling shock in her chest and “the feeling of fear, maybe a flash of a point of time during my assault, and sometimes it was like he was doing it again,” she says.
>
> Several months ago, a friend of Lindsey’s was regaling her with stories about the movie Room, in which the young female protagonist is imprisoned for years in a shed and repeatedly raped. Lindsey hadn’t seen it, didn’t want to see it; yet when her friend said the word trapped, she detected the unwanted caress of her disorder across her body, felt her pulse begin to race.
>
> ... In psychological parlance, a trigger can be any stimulus that transports a PTSD sufferer back to the original scene of her trauma. It might be visual (a red baseball cap like the one an old abuser wore, a gait or facial expression) or aural (a whistle or slamming door). Some people are triggered by the smell of cigarette smoke or traces of a specific perfume. Others react to spoken or **written** language: words that switch on the brain’s stress circuits, bathing synapses in adrenaline and elevating heart rate and blood pressure.
>
> ... When a patient presents with triggers that take the form of **words**, [professor of clinical psychology] Foa says, she encourages him not to skirt contexts in which those **words** might materialize.

[The Trapdoor of Trigger Words](http://www.slate.com/articles/double_x/cover_story/2016/09/what_science_can_tell_us_about_trigger_warnings.html) (subtitle: What the science of trauma can tell us about an endless campus debate), Katy Waldman, 5 Sept 2016, Salon.com (emphasis mine)

Within this topic there is some debate over the definitions of terms such as 'trauma', as Professor Foa explains in the same article:

> Foa isn’t convinced that those with PTSD would suffer flashbacks “reading accounts of what happened” to fictional characters. A “therapeutic distance” exists, she says, between confronting your past and imagining someone else’s. Even though graphic stories retain the power to disturb, Foa says, “I do not appreciate this idea that people should always decide whether or not they will be made upset. If we act as though they cannot handle distressing ideas, we communicate the unhelpful message that they are not strong.”
>
> Foa’s comment illumines a vast gray area in the trigger warning debate. In the fervor around awareness and empowerment, are university activists using the term trauma too loosely? “I question whether hearing words that have a certain connotation because of our culture or historical context really counts as a trauma,” Kaysen says. “They may be really upsetting, but I don’t know that there’s data to suggest that they would cause PTSD symptoms.”

Comment: A dictionary defenition is not a credible source to show the existance of a complex human psychological phenomenon.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed : because it's complex? I agree that it is complex, I don't agree that a good dictionary is not a credible source for the definition of complex words. Better sources are probably out there though, feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: A dictionary gives the meaning of a word, it means that people use this word to confare that meaning, i.e. there are people who use "triger words" also meaning written word. It doesn't mean that they are right and that there is an actual phenomenomn to correspond to the word.

Comment: The dictionary defenition of [ghost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ghost) doesn't mean that ghosts exists, only that people use that word.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question either. The question can a _single_ word trigger a reaction. The dictionary talks about "something read", not what the minimum length of that something is.

Comment: This confirms the claim exists, that people use the word this way, but it's not really evidence that the triggering happens.

Comment: @Sklivvz The question seemed to be asking "do people use the word 'trigger' to mean this?" If the question is "*should* people use the word to mean this?" then in the absence of a clinical definition (I can't find one) no prescriptivist authority exists to make that decision. If native English speakers use the word that way - and it seems they do - then that is what the word means. http://instruct.westvalley.edu/lafave/DFW_present_tense.html

Comment: If people say they are in distress or having a flashback then it would seem odd to tell them they're not. Perhaps it would be possible to contradict them with brain scans but I haven't found any research on that.

Comment: Ah OK, it seems to be a misunderstanding. The question is in the title and reads "Can reading a word trigger a trauma flashback?"

Comment: Found some more content.

Comment: @AE I think that second quote is the answer the OP was looking for. I +1'd but I recommend moving it to the top, and ditching the dictionary definiton.

Comment: It's what I was looking for, although I was hoping for a full study.

Comment: Absent of a psychological double blind large scale study, we can't prove nor deny this claim.